# Infinite Slider

Tags: html, css

HTML

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide-img">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slide-img">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide-img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: baseline;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
.slider img {
  height: 300px;
}
```

I'm trying to have images fill up the entire width. I would like to be able to have these images automatically & continuously move to the left, while replacing the empty space with the first to go off the screen. I've tried to do this with transform, and it works, but it's glitchy. I would like to do this in pure CSS

Comment: This is pure CSS.. What's glitchy about it?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that with CSS and avoid Glitches, you can:

1. Create a a container  and hide the overflow to avoid the elements inside take room in the screen
2. Create a Rail. It should be the total of your elements. e.g. for three elements `width:300%`
3. Define your elements, splitting them by `100`. e.g. for three elements, every element is `33.3%`. In the example at the bottom, you can see it is slightly less because of the predefined styles.
4. To make it infinite, add the first element to the end, to avoid blinking or glitchy behaviour.
5. In the animation, finish it in the left position of the last element. Three elements take 100%, which means the last one starts at 200%. The css animation will reset at `0`, so matching the last element with the first one will match the position of the first one, giving the sensation is the same element. In the example I finished at `201%` to make it smoother having the default styles.

**Result:**

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.rail {
  width: 300%;
}

.rail img {
  width: 33.1%;
  height:200px;
  display: inline;
  animation: 3s scroll linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-201%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rail">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```